# error when declaring an enum to a variable

Tags: c++, enums

I have the following syntax:

```
enum home
{
no,
yes,
}homew;

home homes;

std::string s;
s="no";

homes=s; //is not working. Why?
```

Were am I wrong?

Comment: Don't yell at us, pls (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing strings with enumerated values.

An `enum` variable is simply an integer that you can use a literal for at compile time, nothing more than that.

It makes the code more understandable and self-documenting rather than merely using a number literal.

Comment: should i have to say homes=0?

Comment: @sunset: you would simply say `homes = yes` or `homes = no`.

Answer (score 1):

1. This

   ```
   enum home { no, yes, } homew;
   ```

   defines the ***type*** `home` plus a ***variable*** `homew` of that type.
   Did you intent that? Why?
2. The values defined for an `enum` type are literals, to be used as such:

   ```
   home homes = no;
   ```
3. In C++ there's no built-in way to convert between enum value literals and a string representation of them. If you need this, you'll have to [cook up your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726664/string-to-enum).

Comment: i did add homew at the end of enum home because otherwise i had errors. i couldn't say enum home{..}; home homes;.

Answer (score 0):

enums in C++ are implicitly an `int` data type. You can't assign string values to enum.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't compile because C++ provides no built-in mechanism for converting from `std::string` to an `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

```
typeof(home) != typeof(std::string) // types are not equal
```

Thus, you cannot assign an `enum` to `std::string` or otherwise. Implicit conversion between `enum` and integral types like `bool`, `int` etc. is possible however.

> Is there a way I can solve my problem as it is?

If possible use [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/).

```
std::map<std::string, home> myTypes;
myTypes["yes"] = yes;
myTypes["no"] = no;
```

Now you can do,

```
homes = myTypes["no"];
```

Comment: in my case should i have to write homes-=0? THX

Comment: @sunset, just click on `std::map<key,value>`; it's a container class by itself like `std::string`. You can use this container to relate your `string`(key) and `enum`(value).

Comment: You need to `#include <map>`; just refer to the examples in the link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, enums values are of `int` type. You could instead write a small function that converts from enum to `String` like this:

```
std::string GetStringFromEnum(home iHome)
{
 switch (home)
 {
  case yes: return "yes";
  case no: return "no"; break;
  default: return "here be dragons";
 }
}
```

and vice-versa:

```
home GetEnumFromString(std::string iImput)
{
 if (iImput == "yes") return yes;
 return no; //if you extend the enum beyond 2 values, this function will get more complicated
}
```

and you could modify your code like so:

```
homes = GetStringFromEnum(no)
```

the downside for this approach is that if you modify the enum, you must also modify the convert function.

HTH,
JP