# String to Enum template error

Tags: c++, string, qt, enums

I need to convert a String to enum.

I followed the idea in [String to enum in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726664/string-to-enum)

And this is my code:

```
#ifndef ENUMPARSER_H
#define ENUMPARSER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

enum MYENUM
{
    VAL1,
    VAL2
};
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class EnumParser
{
    map<string, T> enumMap;
public:
    EnumParser();
    T ParseEnum(const string &value)
    {
        map<string, T>::const_iterator iValue= enumMap.find(value);
        if(iValue!=enumMap.end())
            return iValue->second;
    }

};

EnumParser<MYENUM>::EnumParser()
{
    enumMap["VAL1"] = VAL1;
    enumMap["VAL2"] = VAL2;
}

#endif // ENUMPARSER_H
```

When tring to compile it I get the following errors:
[image]

I'm working on QT 4.8.

What is my mistake?

Comment: typename map<string, T>::const_iterator iValue = enumMap.find(value);
const_iterator is dependent name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map<string, T>::const_iterator` is a dependent name, you need:

```
 typename map<string, T>::const_iterator iValue= enumMap.find(value);
```

You can read more about the subject [here](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#dependent).

Comment: When you specialize constructor for MYENUM you have template<> before c-tor?