# c++ macro for saving enum element names and values to file

Tags: c++, macros, enums

Normally I try to avoid the use of macros, so I actually don't know how to use them beyond the very most basic ones, but I'm trying to do some meta-manipulation so I assume macros are needed.

I have an enum listing various log entries and their respective id, e.g.

```
enum LogID
{
  LOG_ID_ITEM1=0,
  LOG_ID_ITEM2,
  LOG_ID_ITEM3=10,
  ...
}
```

which is used within my program when writing data to the log file. Note that they will not, in general, be in any order.

I do most of my log file post-processing in Matlab so I'd like to write the same variable names and values to a file for Matlab to load in. e.g., a file looking like

```
LOG_ID_ITEM1=0;
LOG_ID_ITEM2=1;
LOG_ID_ITEM3=10;
...
```

I have no idea how to go about doing this, but it seems like it shouldn't be too complicated. If it helps, I am using c++11.

edit:
For clarification, I'm not looking for the macro itself to write the file. I want a way to store the enum element names and values as strings and ints somehow so I can then use a regular c++ function to write everything to file. I'm thinking the macro might then be used to build up the strings and values into vectors? Does that work? If so, how?

Comment: As stated it sounds like you could just cut-and-paste. Why do you need to automate this?

Comment: Rarely does anyone NEED a macro, but it just makes things easier. That  enum changes fairly frequently as I change what data is logged so it would be rather convenient to have a ready-made Matlab file generated every time.

Also, copy-paste only works if I explicitly define each enum value.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I don't think you can write a pre-processor macro that will write a file for you. The best you might be able to do is a makefile dependency that generates your .m from your .cpp using a custom processor such as a sed script or similar.

Comment: Possibly related: [String to enum in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726664/string-to-enum-in-c) and [How to convert an enum type variable to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093460/how-to-convert-an-enum-type-variable-to-a-string). But you are likely _not_ going to find the simplicity of expression you are looking for.

Comment: The second link is similar but that solution requires that for each new log item I need to update two separate places: once in the enum and once in the array of strings (which I also can't index by the enum since the enum values are arbitrary).

@AdamBurry - Sorry, I didn't meant to have the macro write the file. I just need it to make a structure that I can use write a file using normal c++ functions. I've edited my post to clarify.

Comment: @ryan0270, read all the solutions proposed above. Some of them only require one list. I did not see one that handled setting the int values though.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Adam Burry that a separate script is likely best for this. Not sure which languages you're familiar with, but here's a quick Python script that'll do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

'''Makes a .m file from an enum in a C++ source file.'''


from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import re


def parse_cmd_line():

    '''Gets a filename from the first command line argument.'''

    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        sys.stderr.write('Usage: enummaker [cppfilename]\n')
        sys.exit(1)
    return sys.argv[1]


def make_m_file(cpp_file, m_file):

    '''Makes an .m file from enumerations in a .cpp file.'''

    in_enum = False
    enum_val = 0
    lines = cpp_file.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        if in_enum:

            # Currently processing an enumeration

            if '}' in line:

                # Encountered a closing brace, so stop
                # processing and reset value counter

                in_enum = False
                enum_val = 0
            else:

                # No closing brace, so process line

                if '=' in line:

                    # If a value is supplied, use it

                    ev_string = re.match(r'[^=]*=(\d+)', line)
                    enum_val = int(ev_string.group(1))

                # Write output line to file

                e_out = re.match(r'[^=\n,]+', line)
                m_file.write(e_out.group(0).strip() + '=' +
                        str(enum_val) + ';\n')
                enum_val += 1
        else:

            # Not currently processing an enum,
            # so check for an enum definition

            enumstart = re.match(r'enum \w+ {', line)
            if enumstart:
                in_enum = True


def main():

    '''Main function.'''

    # Get file names

    cpp_name = parse_cmd_line()
    m_name = cpp_name.replace('cpp', 'm')
    print('Converting ' + cpp_name + ' to ' + m_name + '...')

    # Open the files

    try:
        cpp_file = open(cpp_name, 'r')
    except IOError:
        print("Couldn't open " + cpp_name + ' for reading.')
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
        m_file = open(m_name, 'w')
    except IOError:
        print("Couldn't open " + m_name + ' for writing.')
        sys.exit(1)

    # Translate the cpp file

    make_m_file(cpp_file, m_file)

    # Finish

    print("Done.")

    cpp_file.close()
    m_file.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running `./enummaker.py testenum.cpp` on the following file of that name:

```
/* Random code here */

enum LogID {
    LOG_ID_ITEM1=0,
    LOG_ID_ITEM2,
    LOG_ID_ITEM3=10,
    LOG_ID_ITEM4
};

/* More random code here */

enum Stuff {
    STUFF_ONE,
    STUFF_TWO,
    STUFF_THREE=99,
    STUFF_FOUR,
    STUFF_FIVE
};

/*  Yet more random code here */
```

produces a file `testenum.m` containing the following:

```
LOG_ID_ITEM1=0;
LOG_ID_ITEM2=1;
LOG_ID_ITEM3=10;
LOG_ID_ITEM4=11;
STUFF_ONE=0;
STUFF_TWO=1;
STUFF_THREE=99;
STUFF_FOUR=100;
STUFF_FIVE=101;
```

This script assumes that the closing brace of an `enum` block is always on a separate line, that the first identifier is defined on the line following the opening brace, that there are no blank lines between the braces, that `enum` appears at the start of a line, and that there is no space following the `=` and the number. Easy enough to modify the script to overcome these limitations. You could have your makefile run this automatically.

Comment: Up voted for the effort, but the question has been clarified to make this an incorrect answer.

Comment: @AdamBurry: Well, he clarified the question to say that he doesn't want the macro to actually write the file, and that he "can then use a regular c++ function to write everything to file", but doesn't necessarily mean that having a separate mechanism entirely to write the file won't do equally well, but the OP can clarify if he wants.

Comment: Adam is correct, the intention is that all this is contained within one program. On exit it would automatically generate the Matlab file.

Comment: @ryan0270: I suspect you will not find a good solution, but others may answer. Using a separate script will also avoid kludging and obfuscating your code in order to achieve an entirely ancillary end, which would normally be considered a better design.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered "going the other way"? It usually makes more sense to maintain your data definitions in a (text) file, then as part of your build process you can generate a C++ header and include it. Python and mako is a good tool for doing this.

Comment: Putting the enum in it's own header would simplify things a bit if you go the external processor route.

Comment: Something along those lines is probably the more "correct" way of doing it, but unfortunately it would require major refactoring of what I have already.